# Trying to send mail, but having "Address in mailbox given [xxxx] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2."

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send mail to actual email address.

When user is being registered, I am using user's email address (taken from register form) to send activation link to that email.

When I tried this with mailtrap.io, it showed correct "from" email adress and "to" email address

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('smuiauol@gmail.com')->subject('SMUIA account verification')->view('emails.verify')->with('user', $this->user);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{

   $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'program' => $data['program'],
        'year' => isset($data['year']) ? $data['year'] : null,
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

Now it gives error:

Address in mailbox given [xxxx] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: What is `$data['email']`? Is it possible there's an email in your mailbox with a really busted email address in the headers?

Comment: I used given default laravel syntax for creating user and getting the data for fields, such as name, program, email etc. I did not quite get your question, @tadman :/

Comment: Which line is causing the error? What is the `[xxxx]` part?

Comment: try to see maybe this will help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQoRh_9LkjU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which class is this? you might want to try using the `dd()` functionality to inspect what values you're using in the script.

I was actually writing something very similar to this earlier today. So I'm going to assume that the class is Mail\UserVerify.php. A few things to try

1. Have you verified your template? (it caused an issue for me). - if it's not try creating it and try again
2. Have you tried replacing `$this->user->email` with `$data['email']` to see if it works? - if it does verify that `$this->user->email==$data['email']`.
3. Have you verified that the user is being created in the db? - if it's not then $this->user has no value.

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('smuiauol@gmail.com')
                ->subject('SMUIA account verification')
                ->view('emails.verify')
                ->with('user', $this->user);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{

   $user = User::create([
        'name'    => $data['name'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'program' => $data['program'],
        'year'    => isset($data['year']) ? $data['year'] : null,
        'email'   => $data['email'],
        'password'=> bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token'   => str_random(40)
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)
        ->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

Good luck.